# Описание алгоритма обратного вычитанию одного числа из другого

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Есть 2 текстовых поля и метод, который вычитает число в первом поле из числа во втором. Реализован банальным вычитанием одного числа из другого. Требуется описание алгоритма для обратного метода.

Приведу пример:

Во втором поле число 9999. Если в первое ввести 9 во втором станет 9990, если добавить ещё одну 9 (99) то во втором будет 9900 и т.д. Требуется сделать обратный метод, то есть если в первом поле 999 и во втором 9000, то при удалении 9 из первого во втором должно быть 9900, ещё одной 9990 и т.д. Естественно должно работать не только с девятками :-) метод должен быть арифметически корректным.

Мне не нужна как таковая реализация, а только примерное оформление возможного алгоритма в текст, но примеры кода на любом более-менее читабельном языке приветствуются.

Comment: что будет, если редактировать не первое, а второе число? Кто второй число вообще задает и как?

Comment: Второе число лежит в бд, первое задаётся в ui. Суть в отображении результата в рилтайме, потом коммит.

Comment: То есть, в обратном алгоритме, если в базе 9999, в первом поле 99, то второе поле = база минус первое поле?

Comment: В базе меняется только после подтверждения, этот алгоритм нужен только для визуализации. Суть алгоритма в корректной отмене операции вычитания. По факту есть кастомная клавиатура с цифрами (соответственно ими производится ввод) и кнопкой backspace. В результате введённое число должно быть корректно вычтено из имеющегося в бд и отрисовываться должен каждый шаг ввода/редактирования ввода.

Comment: У вас в вопросе нет ни бд,  ни подтверждений. Вы меня еще больше запутали. То у вас оба числа задаются, то только одно меняется, то в бд что то, то не в бд. Распишите четко прямой алгоритм, кто что задает, что от чего отнимается, с текущим описанием не ясно ничего.

Comment: Про то, откуда берётся значение спросили вы, на мой взгляд это никак не относится к вопросу, но чтобы получить более точный ответ и банально быть вежливым я развёрнуто отвечал на ваши уточняющие вопросы. Алгоритм полностью описан в вопросе. 2 текстовых поля подразумевают под собой отображение на экране обоих чисел. При изменении одного меняется другое. В любом случае скорее всего буду решать через машину состояний. Спасибо за беседу, направили мысли в нужное русло.

Comment: А что такого сложного? При очередной цифре *суммируем* с тем, что было до ввода этой цифры (получаем самое исходное значение, которое, кстати, можно и просто хранить отдельно), и вычитаем то, что там стало после ввода новой цифры...

Comment: Вам вообще не нужны два алгоритма.  Храните в переменной то число, из которого вычитаете. После действия с числом в первом поле ( ввод или удаление цифры) то,  что в нем получилось вычитайте из переменной, результат выводите во второе поле. Когда ввод завершен - смотрите, что получилось во втором поле и отправляйте это на хранение, куда там Вам надо.